# What does "double oughts" mean?

Tags: american-english, history

I've watched some documentary about the 21st century history
in which the narrator said "when the 21st century began, it
didn't even have a name" and then someone replied by saying
"the double oughts."

I think it's related to another name for the 21st century or
literally means double oughts, more responsibilities were added on people.

What does 'double oughts' really mean?

Comment: Hint: In this context "oughts" means zeros.

Answer (score 1):

"*Aught*" and "*ought*" (the latter in its noun sense) strictly speaking mean "all" or "anything", and are not names for the number 0. Nevertheless, they are sometimes used as such in American English, for example, "*aught*" as a placeholder for zero in the pronunciation of the calendar year numbers.

As [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aught) states -

> aught (plural aughts)
>
> 1. [whit](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whit), the smallest part,
>    [iota](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/iota).
> 2. ([archaic](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#archaic))
>    zero
> 3. The digit zero as the decade in years. For example, aught-nine
>    for 1909 or 2009.
>
> The use of "aught" and "[ought](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ought)" to mean "zero" is very much proscribed
> as the word "aught" actually means the opposite of "naught":
> "anything". This may be due to misanalysis, or may simply be the
> result of unknowing speakers confusing the meanings of "aught" and
> "naught" due to similar-sounding phonemes.

Comment: Or it might have been a fad during the first decade of the 1900s. It didn't happen this century, after all, and _ought_ in that sense is dying.

Answer (score -1):

naught

noun

(archaic) All his efforts will have been for naught: nothing, nothing at all, nought, nil, zero;

Comment: You need to cite the source for your definition, and make sure you clearly indicate what is a direct quote (eg with blockquotes or "regular quotes")

Comment: The word 'naught' doesn't appear in the question. I get that it relates to 'ought', but that's not evident.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425399)